# Unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('

Tags: ruby

This is my Rails code:

```
def update
  if @post.update(post_params)
    redirect_to @post, notice: “Update successful”
  else
    render ‘edit’
  end
end
```

I get an error:

/home/mieds/Documents/Marmelade/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:34: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('

Any ideas on why this is thrown?

Comment: check your quotes once - `'edit'` instead of `‘edit’` ? also `"Update successful"` instead of `“Update successful”`

Comment: managed to reproduce in my application. added as answer.

Comment: it happens, mostly copy pasting from some websites...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with your quotes. Change you code with:

```
def update
  if @post.update(post_params)
    redirect_to @post, notice: "Update successful" # changed here
  else
    render 'edit' # changed here
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

`redirect_to posts_path, notice: "Update successful"`